# Show hide div based on multiple checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I have a div ("#CME") that is hidden initially, I need to show it if ALL 6 of these checkboxes are checked.

```
$("#CME").hide();
    (function() {
        if("#CME1") && ("#CMEQL") && ("#CBT1") && ("#CBTQL") && ("#NYM1") && ("#CMX1").is(":checked") {
            $("#CME").show();
        } else {
            $("#CME").hide();
        }
    });
```

This keeps getting an error in firebug. thx.

Comment: Any chance that these are the same checkbox groups you were asking about earlier?

Comment: Unfortunately no, a different group :)

Comment: Alright. Just wanted to make sure these were individual checkboxes we were dealing with. The answer you received below should work, but consider the fact that you're creating a function without invoking it. Perhaps you meant to place a `$` before the `(function(){...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues with your code:

1) Syntax of if is wrong.

2) jQuery object prefix(jQuery/$) is missing in the if condition.

3) is function of jQuery return true even if one element in the selection is satisfiying the is condition which would yield wrong result as per your requirement.

Try this:

```
 $("#CME").hide();
$(function() {
        $("#CME1, #CMEQL, #CBT1, #CBTQL, #NYM1, #CMX1").change(function(){
        var checkBoxes =  $("#CME1, #CMEQL, #CBT1, #CBTQL, #NYM1, #CMX1").filter(":not(:checked)");
            if(checkBoxes.length == 0){
                    $("#CME").show();
            } else {
                    $("#CME").hide();
            }
    });
});
```

Working example @ : http://jsfiddle.net/t5qZ7/5/

Comment: Updated the code ($ was missing infront of the ready function handler.) Try it now?

Comment: @Cybernate @Patrick I think it needs to be a change function. If I check all of them, nothing happens, but If i refresh the page and they are still checked, the div appears.

Comment: @Dirty: Don't take this the wrong way, but if you need it to be on a change event, you need to give some sort of indication of that in the question. As far as we can tell, you only needed this on page load. ;o)

Comment: @Cybernate - man thank you. I really appreciate the help. One day Ill catch on....

Comment: @patrick - no worries, I understand it's constructive criticism. I apologize for not being accurate in my questions, repeatedly. Thanks all.